# This is a run length encoding program for our partner assignment.

Tags: java, run-length-encoding

We are trying to carry out the instruction on the Javadoc. So far we have this but are confused with the index paramter

```
 * Read the next run (or single character) and return the index of the symbol following the run (or symbol read).
   * Store the count and symbol for the run in the run parameter.
   * @param line - the input line being processed
   * @param index - the index of the first character in the next "run" (which might be just a single character)
   * @param run - where to store the symbol and count for the Run
   * @return the index of the symbol following the run just read
   */
  static int getNext(String line, int index, Run run) {
    line.charAt(index); //char first, something about a line
    return ?.symbol;//Store values
    run.count= ?.count; //the given number of that specific symbol or repetition
    enter code here
    run.symbol= ?.symbol; //whatever symbol you first see
    // TO BE COMPLETED

    return index+1;// just to make it advance so starter program doesn't loop infinitely
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the actual RLE compression function, but rather a helper function to count the repetition of the current character that is being processed by the main RLE compression function.

What this seems to need to do is this:

- Take the character at index `index` of string `line`, and store it in the appropriate property of the Run object.
- Iterate over characters in the `line` following index `index`, until you encounter one that's not equal to the one you took at the start.
- Store the amount of found repetitions in the appropriate property of the Run object.
- Return the position in the string at which the non-equal character was encountered.